# error: C2664: 'QXmlStreamWriter::writeAttributes' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QVector<T>' to 'const QXmlStreamAttributes &'

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

I'm used to using the `QStringList() << "a" << "b"` idiom for quickly constructing a QStringList to pass to a function, but when I tried it with `QXmlStreamAttributes`, it didn't work.

This code compiles:

```
QXmlStreamAttributes attributes;
attributes << QXmlStreamAttribute("a", "b");
writer.writeAttributes(attributes);
```

But this one fails:

```
writer.writeAttributes(QXmlStreamAttributes() << QXmlStreamAttribute("a", "b"));
```

It fails with error:

```
C:\Workspace\untitled5\mainwindow.cpp:18: error: C2664: 'QXmlStreamWriter::writeAttributes' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QVector<T>' to 'const QXmlStreamAttributes &'
with
[
    T=QXmlStreamAttribute
]
Reason: cannot convert from 'QVector<T>' to 'const QXmlStreamAttributes'
with
[
    T=QXmlStreamAttribute
]
No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

### Another thing I noticed:

This code compiles:

```
QVector<QXmlStreamAttribute> v1 = (QVector<QXmlStreamAttribute>() << QXmlStreamAttribute("a", "b"));
```

But this one doesn't, even though QXmlStreamAttributes inherits from `QVector<QXmlStreamAttribute>`:

```
QXmlStreamAttributes v2 = (QXmlStreamAttributes() << QXmlStreamAttribute("a", "b"));
```

It fails with the same error.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QStringList` has

```
operator<<(const QString & str)
```

but `QVector` has

```
QVector<T> &    operator<<(const T & value)
```

so your

```
QVector<QXmlStreamAttribute> v1 = (QVector<QXmlStreamAttribute>() << QXmlStreamAttribute("a", "b"));
```

compiles successfully.

But your mistake is that `QXmlStreamAttributes` has no copy constructor, but you try use it, so you have 2 solutions:

Use `append`:

```
QXmlStreamAttributes v2;
v2.append(QXmlStreamAttribute("a", "b"));
qDebug()<< v2.first().name();
```

Or use `<<` in some different way:

```
QXmlStreamAttributes v2;
v2 << QXmlStreamAttribute("a", "b");
qDebug()<< v2.first().name();
```

Output is `"a"` in both cases.

[`QXmlStreamAttributes`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qxmlstreamattributes.html) [`QStringList`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstringlist.html#operator-lt-lt) [`QVector`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvector.html#operator-lt-lt)

Comment: So `QXmlStreamAttributes` doesn't automatically inherit the operator << ()?

Comment: @sashoalm I edited my answer and added better explanation about this, see it please.