# How to add multiple attributes in same element in XML file in QT 4.8

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I am looking add multiple attributes in my XML file using `QT 4.8`. It will be something like this:-

```
<Communication xmlns="http://tempuri.org/communication.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

For this use `QXmlStreamWriter xw` and create an element by this line:-

```
xw.writeStartElement(fileID);
```

Now I try to add my attributes:-

```
xw.writeAttribute("xmlns=","http://tempuri.org/communication.xsd");
xw.writeAttribute("xmlns:xs=","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
```

but unfortunately `writeAttribute` function can only work only just after creating element. Please [read here](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qxmlstreamwriter.html#writeAttribute-2) about this. So, I am getting my output like this:-

```
<Communication xmlns:xs="http://tempuri.org/communication.xsd">
```

So, I wonder how can multiple attribute be added in same element. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What about [`QXmlStreamWriter::writeAttributes()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qxmlstreamwriter.html#writeAttributes)?

Comment: that's what I am using bro, But it can't be used twice for same element. Please read doc

Comment: The one I mentioned takes [`QXmlStreamAttributes`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qxmlstreamattributes.html#details) which _represents a **vector** of `QXmlStreamAttribute`_.

Comment: I can't figure out how to use it

Comment: Doesn't the doc. help? I'm not experienced - just googled out of curiosity. The doc. says: _New attributes can be added with `append()`._ Sounds easy to me...

Comment: I believe you have to append all attributes to an instance of `QXmlStreamAttributes` and then you may add this instance (with all attributes at once) to the element using `QXmlStreamWriter::writeAttributes()`.

Comment: I got it, here is the answer:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132855/error-c2664-qxmlstreamwriterwriteattributes-cannot-convert-parameter-1-f